# Angular app fails to run and displays invalid config error

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building my angular app from the angular cli starter.
The problem is being suggested in the error below.

> C:\Users\Afropepe\Desktop\development\buy-ticket\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config\config.js:76
>                   throw new InvalidConfigError(common_tags_1.stripIndent 
>                   ^ InvalidConfigError: Parsing 'C:\Users\Afropepe\Desktop\development\buy-ticket.angular-cli.json'
>   failed. Ensure the file is valid JSON. Error: Unexpected token ] in
>   JSON at position 535
>       at InvalidConfigError (C:\Users\Afropepe\Desktop\development\buy-ticket\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config\config.js:11:9)
>       at Function.fromConfigPath (C:\Users\Afropepe\Desktop\development\buy-ticket\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config\config.js:76:19)
>       at Function.fromProject (C:\Users\Afropepe\Desktop\development\buy-ticket\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\config.js:88:46)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Afropepe\Desktop\development\buy-ticket\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\build.js:7:35)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)

Comment: update the post with the project folder or share a github repo link

Comment: i solved the problem some time back i think by re installing typescript i think and i solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Please ensure your file named ".angular-cli.json" contains JSON format, in my case I added some comments on the JSON file, and even when VS compile, this is not valid

- "assets": [ "assets"],
- //"index": "myindexfile.html",
- "main": "main.ts",

  Please make sure your file is has a right JSON format

The error that I was getting is below:

- \@angular\cli\models\config\config.js:89
             throw new InvalidConfigError(common_tags_1.stripIndent `
             ^

Answer (score 1):

I had some error, when tried to import in angular-cli.json in scripts file

```
 "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js"
```

after

```
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
```

So maybe this problem occurs when the one library needs to include another library before it.

Answer (score 1):

**angular-cli.json Content:**

> //"index": "index.html",
>         "main": "main.ts",
>         "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
>         "test": "test.ts",

Inside the .angular-cli.json/ angular-cli.json just **remove ////"index": "index.html"**, because it won't considering as comment and throw some exception.

**Correct Output:**

```
  "main": "main.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same error, resolved by replacing with new angular-cli.json and reconfigure.

Comment: How so by deleting your existing angular clis json??